# Swift make a http request response as array

Tags: ios, swift

I have got this swift http request

```
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.web.com/ajax/logreg.php")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let pass = pass_text_field.text!.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .queryValueAllowed)!
    let postString = "app_reg_pass=\(pass)"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("error=\(error!)")
            return
        }
        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {                           print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print(response!)
        }

        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print(responseString!)
    }
    task.resume()
```

Reponse string:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => Murad
)
```

And my response to this code is array.But when i try to treat response as array it gives me an error.How can i turn response into array so i can do this 
`response[0]`?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @pierreafranck `Type 'URLResponse?' has no subscript members`

Comment: @sakoaskoaso your response is in JSON format?

Comment: @ReinierMelian no just an array

Comment: Edit your question and paste the response string you're getting

Comment: @sakoaskoaso an array of what? XML objects, JSON objects?

Comment: @mag_zbc i added it.

Comment: @ReinierMelian array of integers and strings

Comment: Your webservice response must be in a parsable format (xml or json) then you will be able to parse result to convert as Array

Comment: If your webservice is in PHP you just have to replace output by `echo json_encode($myArray)`

Comment: @Maxime okay thanks!

Comment: @Maxime but how do i get that in Swift?

Comment: For swift part take a look at @Paolo answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is most likely coming in as a JSON object, so you need to deserialize it before you can use the results.

```
do {
    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [Any]

    print(jsonData[0] as! Int)    // should print "1"
    print(jsonData[1] as! String) // should print "Murad"

} catch {
    print("An error occurred")
}
```

Comment: `Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x1033a2a98) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1033a4208).`

Comment: @sakoaskoaso try it now, I changed it to cast to an array instead of a dictionary

Comment: You have to cast result in Array of dictionary :

    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [[String: Int]]

Comment: Thanks for thy answer!